# IE8 - Photos aren't displaying the same, because their source image is different size

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer-8, size

My site consists of 5 divs (represented by green boxes). The problem is that some divs are linked to images that are larger than the images in the other divs. This size difference causes them to display differently in IE8. Divs linked to larger images display incorrectly in **IE8.**

Here is a screenshot showing them displaying **correctly** in IE9:

[image: IE9]

and here is them displaying **incorrectly** in IE8:

[image]

You can see the red house (far-right) displays properly because it's linked to a smaller photo (500px wide). Whereas the other divs are linked to photos much larger. The div HTML is:

```
<a href="http://www.demo.com/adfadfadfa">
   <div class="block personal fl">
   <div class="content">
   <p class="price">
<p class="vignette" style="background-image:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Ellen_H._Swallow_Richards_House_Boston_MA_01.jpg)"></p>
   </p>
     </div>

 <ul class="features">
<li class="titlebox">adfadfadf </li>
<li>adfadfadf</li>
<li>adfadfadf</li>
    </ul>
     </div>              
</a>
```

I want to change the CSS code so that it makes all photos the same width/height no matter their source image's size. The CSS relevant to display the image is:

```
.vignette {
       width: 90%;
       margin-left:auto;
       margin-right:auto;
       margin-bottom:-5%;
        box-shadow: 15px 15px 40px #A1F997 inset,-15px -15px 40px #A1F997 inset;
        height: 290px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Here is my demo site: http://testsite24.netai.net/public/demo2.html

How do I make all images the same size as the red house image?

Thank you!

Comment: background-size: cover is not supported in IE8 so the images are full sized.

Comment: Ok, but how do I make this work in IE8?  Change what-to-what?   Thank you

Comment: Could use smaller images or instead use <img> and set its width and height instead of background-images.

Comment: That doesn't seem very dynamic if I'm setting a definite width for each photo using html. Isn't there a way to use a larger image, but just shrink it down using CSS? (maintaining aspect ratio)

Comment: your right that was a bad suggestion.  You could wrap the images in a div and scale that div.  Then you could set the image to position: absolute and the left, right, top, and bottom to 0 so the image covers the div scaling it.